# What does "controlling expression" mean?

Tags: c

I don't understand the definition of this word, can someone help me to understand?

When I was reading this slide, I saw this word. I tried to search on Cambridge Dictionary but I couldn't find anything useful

[image: "The switch statement is especially useful when the selection is based on the value of a single variable or of a simple expression (called the controlling expression)"]

Comment: The image you linked to shows that the "controlling expression" is simply the expression in the `switch ( )`.

Comment: @DanielWalker -- _controlling expression_ is a term used frequently in the C Standard itself, and `switch` statements are one of the places these occur.

Comment: `"controlling expression"`, look at [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming))

Comment: The paragraph you quote is providing the definition of "controlling expression".

Answer (score 4):

A *controlling expression* is simply one that controls what a particular statement will do.  The example you posted shows such an expression for a `switch` statement.  Such expressions also occur in:

- `if`
- `while`
- `do...while`
- `for`

This term is used throughout the C standard, although it is not formally defined.

Answer (score 3):

The controlling expression of a statement is the expression that controls the path of execution of that statement.

The term is used to distinguish a specific expression in a statement from other expressions that might be found in the same statement.

For example, consider the following statement:

```c
if ( f() )
   x = 123;
```

It includes five expressions:

- `f`
- `f()`
- `x`
- `123`
- `x = 123`

But only `f()` is the controlling expression of that `if` statement.
So, for example, when the standard says "the controlling expression of an `if` statement shall have scalar type", this means that `f()` must have scalar type.

The standard uses the term to refer to an expression of the following:

- `_Generic` selection
- Selection statements, in general and for each type of selection statement:

  - `if` statement
  - `switch` statement
- Iteration statements, in general and for each type of iteration statement:

  - `while` statement
  - `do` statement
  - `for` statement